# The condition for $\lim(a_nb_n)=\lim(a_n)\lim(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen many proofs here for
$(n!)^{1/n}$ being divergent.
But suppose, if we consider
$$(n!)^{1/n}=(1\cdot 2\cdots n)^{1/n}
       =(1)^{1/n}\cdots(n)^{1/n}$$

Here each individual term converges to 1.

I know this is not true as $(n!)^{1/n}$ is divergent. So, is there a condition to $\lim(a_n b_n)=\lim(a_n)\lim(b_n)$?

Comment: You have been around for three years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: I don't have a luxury to use laptops or computer. I have a mobile. With due respect, I don't know anything about MathJax. Some people are not that rich you know.

Comment: For product of two sequences it is true but for not a product where the number of factors is increasing with $n$.

Comment: @SatyabratRath I use MathJax even when I am posting on my cellphone. And you don't have to be rich to learn MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converge, i.e. $$\lim a_n = A, \lim b_n = B$$ then
$$\lim a_nb_n = \lim a_n \lim b_n = AB$$
You can extend this to the case when the number of sequences involved is **finite**, by induction.

---

The issue with your example is that it doesn't fit in the above category, i.e. since the number of product terms *are not finite* as $n\to\infty$. Do you see the problem?